# what should be the query to search for this criteria

Tags: sql

I have a table S_EVT_ACT with fields SR_ID,STATUS,TYPE.

TYPE can be NT, HLT and LSP and there are some more values. There may be more than one record with different types and same SR_ID. I want to select that SR_ID where in TYPE is not NT and HLT and status of all other records for that SR_ID is complete. Even if there is one record with incomplete status, I want to reject that SR_ID.

Comment: To be clear: The record you're actually selecting (with Type NOT IN (NT,HLT) — does that record *also* have be Status = 'complete'?  Of can that record be incomplete?

Comment: @Larry Lustig: it seems clear to me from the last sentence in the spec that the row in question should be rejected.

Comment: Do you want only distinct `SR_ID` values or do you want entire rows where the conditions are met?

Comment: @onedaywhen: Yes, but the sentence before says the status of "all *other* records for that SR_ID".  So I think it's unclear.  I'm not saying your interpretation is wrong (I'd give better than even odds that you're right), I just want to be completely clear about it.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SR_ID,STATUS,TYPE FROM S_EVT_ACT
WHERE TYPE NOT IN ('NT', 'HLT')
AND SR_ID NOT IN (SELECT SR_ID FROM S_EVT_ACT WHERE STATUS <> 'Complete')
```

Something like that?

Comment: what i want to say is that for all records for a particualar srid status should be complete

Comment: this query says that "there are no srid rows in the table with the value we are currently looking that that have an incomplete status" - ie "all srids for this value are complete".

Comment: OP: put another way, what the second subquery says is there should be **no** rows for the particualar SR_ID where status is **not** complete. Note the double negative, making it equivalent to your statement. @AndyC: I think this is what they want, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

If i got it correctly, this query will works;

```
select [SR_ID],[STATUS],[TYPE]
from S_EVT_ACT S
where 1=1
and S.[TYPE] not in ('NT','HLT')
and S.[SR_ID] not in (select distinct(se.[SR_ID]) from S_EVT_ACT se  where se.[STATUS] <> 'completed')
```

Comment: as i said, there may be more than one record for same srid but the status may be different. I want to select only that srid for which all the records status are complete.

Comment: Query modified to not include incompleted SR_ID's.